# Rails - Not hitting while loop when creating classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a create method in Rails where I am trying to create multiple objects in a while loop. For some reason it doesn't seem to be hitting the while loop so no objects are being created. The code is below:

```
def create
@user = User.find(params[:participant][:user_id])
@activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
weeks = @activity.weeks
i = 1
while i <= weeks do
  puts "Test"
  participant = Participant.new
  participant.user_id = @user.id
  participant.activity_id = @activity.id
  participant.attended = false
  participant.paid = false
  participant.week = i
  participant.save

  i = i+1
end

redirect_to user_activities_path(@user, :id => @activity.id)


end
```

The form I am using to submit is working fine as I can see from the console, and the redirect_to method at the end is working, so it just seems to be missing the loop. If it helps, the value of weeks is 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can also do `@activity.times do |i|` and then inside the loop `participant.week = i + 1`. A bit more ruby-like way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple `Test` have been output, try `participant.save!`, i think the participant save might fail, like some column not valid, so no objects are being created.

Comment: Thank you, that let me see where it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if activity record is get fetched. I think your 3rd statement should be as follow.

```
@activity = Activity.find(params[:participant][:activity_id])
```